# Jquery Ajax request made into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, modular

I'm working on a school project which uses a lot of ajax. To spare myself some time copy-pasting and a lot of room in the main code I want to create modular ajax functions. Found some examples on stackoverflow but somehow I'm not capable of getting the output that I want.

```
function retrieveAjax(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url, dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            return data;
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            return [{request: request, status: status, error: error}];
        }
    });
}

console.log(retrieveAjax('../functions/getcourses.php'));
```

The log for the data appears, the request is made and results are shown, but in the last console it appears to return undefined.

Any help would be appreciated

Edit:
After reading the original question on which my question was a duplicate, I tried this:

```
function foo(callback, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url, dataType: 'json',
        success: callback
    });
}

function myCallBack(result) {
    console.log(result);
}

foo(myCallBack(), '../functions/getcourses.php');
```

Unfortunatly I can not seem to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Smooth, what does /getcourses.php return?

Comment: `[{"course_id":1,"name":"PHP"},{"course_id":2,"name":"Java"}]`

Comment: In the succes handler, data is shown correctly

Comment: Thanks Satpal, I think I can find a possible way with that

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/bXaGm4Tunv07r9bcofZX?p=preview @Smooth

Comment: Datsik I tried your version, it returns the given url.

Comment: @Datsik Didn't use @ to notify you about the comment.

Comment: @Smooth you should use the server url for ajax call. Don't use `..` or relative paths like `'../functions/getcourses.php'`. Use it like `http://localhost/test/functions/getcources.php`

Comment: @RohanKumar Why is that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wc3aojym/1/ @Smooth